# Use Neo4j in a web project

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a project in which I house 300 000 companies data in mysql database . What I need to do is fill in some of these data in neo4j only once , so that later on companies can set some relations . So companies will be able to create new relations but I must create the nodes and test some queries (traverses) for these relations . So, my idea is like this :

```
public class EnterCompaniesToNeo4j {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("build\\web\\NEO4J databases\\db1"); 
    Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx();
    Node n = null;
    try
    {
        n = graphDB.createNode();
        n.setProperty( "taxnumber", "100000709" );
        System.out.println(n.getProperty("taxnumber"));
        tx.success();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        tx.failure();
    }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }
    graphDB.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it .
I am using Netbeans and tomcat .

Comment: Adding a few imports you have a working skeleton for adding nodes to a neo4j instance. As for 'the right way to do it', to do what exactly?

Comment: I was thinking on having a public static void main where I make the nodes based on the data from mysql database and having a servlet where I allow users to create relationship in that graph .

Comment: Depending on your experience, there is a spring integration http://www.neo4j.org/develop/spring that might help.

Comment: And don't add a single node per transaction, that will be slow. Add at least a few thousand. There's some limited documentation on import options http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import